# The problem is "return $this->db->affected_rows();" or in javascript when switching pages

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I want to be redirected to a certain page after completing the deletion command within 5 seconds in Codeigniter 3. Because knowledge is self-taught, I still can't solve it.

here my Js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".deleteTopic", function(){
        var topicid = $(this).data("topicid"),
            hitURL = baseURL + "dien_dan/delete_topic",
            currentRow = $(this);
        
        var confirmation = confirm("Bạn thật sự muốn xóa chủ đề này?");
        
        if(confirmation)
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url : hitURL,
            data : { topicid : topicid } 
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);              
                if(data.status = true) { 
                alert("Đã xóa thành công chủ đề");
                function Redirect() {
                    window.location.href = baseURL + "dien_dan";
                    }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    Redirect();
                    }, 5000);
                }
                else if(data.status = false) { alert("Xóa chủ đề không thành công !"); }
                else { alert("Access denied..!"); }
            });
        }
    });

    
});
```

My Controller:

```
function delete_topic()
    {
            $topicid = $this->input->post('topicid');
            
            $result = $this->forums_model->delete_topic($topicid);
            $this->forums_model->delete_topic_involve($topicid);
            if ($result > 0) { echo(json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE))); }
            else { echo(json_encode(array('status'=>FALSE))); }
    }
```

And my Model

```
public function delete_topic($topic_id)
        {
                
                // Trừ số lượng chủ đề
                $data_topic = $this->forums_model->get_topic_by_id($topic_id);
                $topic_author = $data_topic['author_id'];
                
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $data_user = $this->user_model->getUserInfo($topic_author);
                $user_update = array(
                    "amo_topic" => $data_user->amo_topic - 1,
                    );
                $this->db->where('userId', $topic_author);
                $this->db->update('tbl_users', $user_update);
                
                $this->db->where('topic_id', $topic_id);
                $this->db->delete('tbl_topics');
            
            
                return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }
```

I have researched and fixed many ways. However, until now I have not been able to determine where the error is to focus on. Looking forward to your help.

Thank for help

Comment: your if should have double or triple equals: `if(data.status == true)` or just remove the equals `if(data.status)`

Comment: @Pete well spotted! I always miss that without an IDE to tell me off :)